# Perl - Enter a row to .csv file only after all duplicates in hash have printed

Tags: perl, excel, csv

I have an array of Catalog Codes. There are many duplicates.  I've used the following to find unique values and the number of duplicates:

```
my %myHash = ();

foreach (@cc) {
  $myHash{$_}++;
}

foreach ( sort keys %myHash ) {
  print "\n $_ : $myHash{$_}";
}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
PM01  :  10<br>
PM02  :  10<br>
PM03  :  6<br>
etc..
```

Okay, now I would like to print OUT some lines to a .csv file.

My goal is to create some sort of if statement that does the following logic:

1. Find out how many duplicates of first hash key, print $number_of_duplicates.  These lines are all similar.
2. After finished, print a NEW line, with some things.  This line will be printed after a line for each duplicate has printed.  This line is similar with other lines printed after duplicates.
3. Repeat for all hash keys.

To be clear, I have already printed out what I need correctly.  My question is how do I print an extra line after each duplicate has been printed?

For example, let's assume this is what is printed OUT:

```
PM01
PM01
PM01
PM01
PM01
PM01
PM01
PM01
PM01
PM01
NEW LINE HERE
PM02
PM02
PM02
PM02
PM02
PM02
PM02
PM02
PM02
PM02
NEW LINE HERE
etc..
```

Comment: Sorry about not completing the title.  The significance of the excel tag is because I am manipulating an excel spreadsheet and thought perhaps someone might ask, are you doing this for an excel spreadsheet?  The answer would be yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach my $key ( sort keys %myHash ) {

  foreach my $iterator ( 1 .. $myHash{$key} ) {

      print $key, "\n";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```